# Is it possible to find the factorial of 10000 in java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to find the factorial of 10000 in java?
I has done the program to find the factorial of 1000 using BigInteger but when i tried to find factorial of 10000 i  am not getting the output.

```
class Factorial{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Factorial fact= new Factorial();


        fact= getFactorialOf(10000);

    }

    void getFactorialOf(long n) {
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
            result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        System.out.println(result);

    }
```

This is my complete code.

Comment: So what are you getting?

Comment: @KumarAbhinav: Why would you suggest using `BigDecimal` to find an integer factorial?

Comment: "i am not getting the output" is never enough information. Please post the code you've tried, and explain exactly what you're seeing - is the program just hanging? Crashing? Exiting with no output? What happens when you debug?

Comment: Here is the code      void getFactorialOf(int n) {
  BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
   result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
  System.out.println(result);

 }

Comment: @Madhupriya edit the question to include the code, not put it in comment. Minor code in comment must be put in backticks `like this` to make it readable

Comment: The code in your comment works just fine for me.  Put a complete compileable / runnable example into the Question.  (The only possible explanation for it working for me and not for you is that you have your own implementation of BigInteger.)

Comment: @Stephan Are you getting the  answer for factorial(10000)??

Comment: Please my question is "Are you getting the value for 10000!??"

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.  According to http://gimbo.org.uk/texts/ten_thousand_factorial.txt, 10000 factorial has 35,659 decimal digits ... but that is well within the capabilities of `BigInteger`.

Which suggests that your problem is that either you have a bug in your code, or you are being impatient.

Comment: The iterative solution takes about 0.2s on my machine.

Comment: @chryslis -  maybe he has chosen to implement this in a pessimal way.  But you are right, the "bug" explanation is the more likely one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class UniqueFact {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
       int n = s.nextInt();
       String fact = factorial(n);
       System.out.println("Factorial is " + fact);
   }

   public static String factorial(int n) {
       BigInteger fact = new BigInteger("1");
       for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
           fact = fact.multiply(new BigInteger(i + ""));
       }
       return fact.toString();
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of BigInteger.ONE use the string parametrized constructor i.e. BigInteger("your_number_string");